# CArray not de-allocating memory

Tags: c++, arrays, windows, memory, mfc

I have a very simple problem and I seem to be stumped at whatever is happening. Look at the following code:

```
CArray<double, double&> arr;
arr.SetSize(50000);

for(int i =0; i< 50000; i++)
{
    arr[i] = (i+2)*3.14f;
}

arr.RemoveAll();
```

I would assume that after `RemoveAll()`, the memory would be freed but it seems like it is not happening. To check memory footprint, open Taskmanager and watch your exe's Memory. It increases on `arr.SetSize()` call but it never decreases even when this `arr` goes out of scope. Can somebody shed some light on nthis?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**First thing:**

## Task Manager != Memory Profiler

The operating system (or more specifically the C runtime system) would certainly cache some of the memory you allocate.

Note that the operating system usually isn't dumb - if it's memory that's not being used by the application and the OS needs more memory to satisfy some other program's memory needs, it will allocate accordingly. But if that's not the case (it isn't most of the time), then keeping it for the application to reuse when is a winning strategy.

Because of these sort of optimizations, you really can't use Task Manager to get an accurate view of an application's memory usage.

**Second thing:**

Like all non-stupid dynamic array classes, `CArray` doesn't release the memory backing the array even when you remove all the elements in case you need to use the memory buffer again. It would be an awful waste of processor cycles to delete the underlying memory buffer only to find that you need to waste even more processor cycles to reallocate another buffer to handle your next `CArray::Append()` call that might come right after a `CArray::RemoveAll()`.

Should you really want to get rid of that extra space, use [CArray::FreeExtra()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/6zz6tb6x.aspx). Note that the function may involve allocating a new buffer and copying the elements over to the new one, then deleting the old buffer.

Comment: I tried FreeExtra but it still doesn't work. I know that task manager is not memory profiler but that is something which is most readily available. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @In Silico, Why would FreeExtra require a new buffer to be allocated to reduce size?  Sure, if it uses realloc to shrink the amount of memory used you end up with a fragmented heap, you avoid the memory overhead of additional heap space, and time overhead of copying and calling ctors and dtors.

Comment: @Shane MacLaughlin: That's one way it could work. But the documentation doesn't specify nor make any guarantees on having it work like that (I've reworded the sentence). And it isn't universal; for example `std::vector` would almost certainly have to allocate a new buffer and delete the old one since the allocator interface doesn't have `realloc()` capability.

Comment: @Aamir, regardless of what CArray is doing, there is no guarantee when the heap manager will return memory to the OS.  Typically, if you have allocated anything after your array, the heap will be fragmented, so while the memory might be available to your program it wont be available to to OS or other programs.  Look up heapwalk for some more info.

Comment: @In Silico, just has a look at the MFC array class source, and you're quite right, my bad.  I rewrote my own array classes some years back, having been using CArray, as the MFC implementations are slow and greedy.

Answer (score 2):

As the others stated, RemoveAll does not release the memory that CArray allocated, you need to call CArray::FreeExtra.

You said that the memory does not go down after CArray's destructor. CArray::SetSize allocates memory from the heap, CArray's destructor frees it. But that does not mean that the heap memory is given back to the operating system.

When you are using MFC I suggest that from time to time you start your program in the debugger. MFC debug applications print out their memory leaks (based on new) during MFC cleanup.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call [FreeExtra](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6zz6tb6x%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) after your RemoveAll to get the memory back.  I'm guessing this is an effort to avoid heap fragmentation.